# Notifications in Electron are empty

Tags: notifications, electron

I am using Electron.js with the HTML5 Notification API. I am attempting to display a notification as soon as my application loads. I am using a BrowserView in my BrowserWindow. Once the app loads, the notification appears, but it defaults to an empty body and the title displays the default Electron text.

I have instantiated this in both the window, and app levels of the application. I have read that it needs to be placed in renderer.js, however, adding it to this file leads to the same results. Any guidance is appreciated.

So far this has only been tested on my machine using OSX Catalina 10.15.03

```
app.on('load', () => {
    let doNotification = new Notification('Do it',
    {
        body: 'Just do it!'
    });
    doNotification.show();
});
```

Comment: Instantiating new HTML5 Notifications immediately shows the notification, you don't need to call the `show` method. Are you sure you're not using the [Electron's notification module](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/notification) which is different that than HTML5 notifications and requires you to add title and a body property and use the `show` method?

Comment: Try this: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/notifications – fwiw, I haven't had any success replacing the `Electron` logo in `Notifications` – even when the published app has its own icon.  If I specify an "icon" property, it gets added to the right side of the notification.

Comment: Thank you both for pointing me in the right direction. I had a reference to it in my main.js file. Removed it, then followed the example to the letter in the electron guide without wrapping it in an event listener and that did the trick. I also need to get rid of the Electron icon now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call the notification in the index.js file as notifications will not be able to access the browser API there. It must be called in the renderer.js which will be able to access the browser APIs.